# Android game score int add in access database through servlet

Tags: java, android, database, servlets

I am not sure on how to go about this but I have a game which I want to expand further and let the user submit the score with their name.

This will submit the score and name to a servlet which will add the details into an access database.

The score is of an int type.

Would be great if someone could show me how to do this, or point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android, just pass score and name as request parameters in URL.

```
String url = "http://example.com/servlet?score=" + score + "&name=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
// Connect the URL.
```

In the servlet, just access them as request parameters.

```
int score = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("score"));
String name = request.getParameter("name");
// Save them in DB.
```

#### See also:

- [Executing a HTTP GET request with HttpClient in Android](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-get-request-with-httpclient)
- [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Comment: Great thank you so much, this helps quite a lot. How can I put the information from the servlet into the access database?

Comment: Use JDBC. This is however a whole story apart. I've posted a tutorial link. If you stucks, ask a more specific question.